# Force free shared memory

Tags: ubuntu, memory

I seem to have about 10Gb of shared memory consumed, I believe by a process that I terminated with `ctrl-C`.

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       706Mi       1.9Gi        10Gi        28Gi        19Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi       4.0Gi          0B
```

Here's the output of `htop`, sorted on % memory use:

[image]

There do not seem to be any processes that can account for this. I definitely had a memory intensive program running at one point, but as mention I killed it. I'd like to run it again, but it's now unable to run because of memory issues. In addition, I checked

```
$ ipcs -a --human

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      size         messages

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      size       nattch     status
0x00000000 13         kevin      600            4M     2          dest
0x00000000 48         kevin      600            4M     2          dest
0x00000000 49         kevin      600           64M     2          dest

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems

$
```

I can reboot the system of course, but it's a server at work, and I don't always have physical access to start it back up. Is there a way to force that memory to be freed?

Comment: tmpfs (eg mounted on /tmp also /run /run/user/* etc.) uses shared memory

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
sync
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

This will clear system buffer and cache. Better if done when server is not under heavy workload.

Comment: I tried this a bit earlier based on some other posts here and didn't notice any change :-(.

Comment: What kind of job does this server do? Webserver?

Comment: No, it's a linux desktop I use for scientific computing, but I usually ssh in from my mac

Comment: Did you tune some kernel parameters? That swap usage with plenty of ram still available is strange too.

Comment: I didn't (at least, I don't think I did). If it makes a difference, it's running `Pop!_os` (which I think is mostly Ubuntu). But this is my first real experience with running a linux OS, so I've avoided messing about with anything low level.

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to identify the cause? The following might be useful for the future other readers:

I've just done my memory usage investigation. I used `df -h` to see memory used by `tmpfs` systems, then used `ps -eo pid,rss,trs,drs,comm` copying output to Libre Calc and summing up rss (resident memory a process takes in kilobytes; trs -size of executable code - turned about to be small, but drs - memory other than executable code - much larger than rss and manual for `ps` did not say whether it in bytes or kilobytes or else, so I found no usage for it).

At the end I reconciled with error margin of ~100Mb:

```
available memory = total - sum (rss) - sum (used tmpfs).
```

P.S. as for shared memory, I was surprised `ipcs` do not output bytes with pids, only one or another, so I skipped that part (at least for now).

Comment: I was never able to track it down, no. Thanks for adding response - in the end I went with a different approach and just figured out a better way to remote restart the server without physical access :-/