# How do I delete shared memory that was used by mounted tmpfs directory?

Tags: bash, memory, tmpfs, memory-management

I executed this command to create a RAM-Disk:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=60G tmpfs /tmp/ramdisk
```

After that I copied several files into this virtual filesystem as follows:

```
cp /mnt/user/hugefile.bin /tmp/ramdisk/hugefile.bin
cp /mnt/user/hugefile2.bin /tmp/ramdisk/hugefile2.bin
cp /mnt/user/hugefile3.bin /tmp/ramdisk/hugefile3.bin
```

Then, the last of the `cp` commands freezed and the CPU load hit the maximum. I think because the size of the RAM-Disk was larger than the free memory. I interrupted it by CTRL+C.

After a while I deleted the mounted RAM-Disk as follows:

```
umount /tmp/ramdisk
```

But and thats now my problem, it did not freed the shared memory:

```
free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             62           0           0          53          61           7
Swap:             0           0           0
```

As you can see there is no high usage on virtual memory:

```
df -BG | grep tmpfs
tmpfs                 1G     1G        1G   1% /run
devtmpfs             32G     0G       32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                32G     0G       32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 1G     1G        1G   1% /var/log
tmpfs                 4G     0G        4G   0% /tmp/plextranscode
```

I found [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/398886/318765) to use `ipcs` to analyze the usage, but the result is empty:

```
ipcs

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages    

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems
```

I found [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/566396/101920) as well, but I'm afraid of killing data of other processes. Isn't there a more selective solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found this solution as well, but I'm afraid of killing data of other processes. Isn't there a more selective solution?

`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` does not and cannot kill any processes or cause any harm to your system - it just evicts everything from your caches, **not** shared memory. `ipcs` has no relationship to your issue either.

`tmpfs` indeed occupies shared memory but unmounting a `tmpfs` mount point must automatically free your shared memory. Why hasn't it happened for you, I've no idea.

I believe your `/tmp/ramdisk` is still mounted but for some reasons `df` doesn't show it.

`reboot` will fix your issue.

Comment: Sad, but if this is the only solution I'll `reboot`